# iOS : App get stuck on Splash screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have tried everything regarding app clean up, project clean xcode quit and all related stuff but still same issue.

I have check everything window also have rootViewController  and everything is assigned.

Comment: Is this happening in simulator or device or both?

Comment: Can you provide code of the application did finish method?

Comment: Try to debug placing breakpoint sin your rootviewcontroller's viewdidload,viewwillappear

Comment: I guess you recently updated mac os or Xcode. Wait for 2-3 mins with splash screen.

Answer (score 4):

After updating to xcode 12, I faced this issue. xcode hangs while attaching debugger to ios process. Deleting the contents of *~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport* worked for me. (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123068?answerId=420683022#420683022)

Comment: Just deleting the content inside devicesupport folder somehow not working for me. I still need to restart the xcode and did a clean build folder action in order to resolve this issues.

Comment: Brilliant! Saved my day !

Answer (score 2):

Try to **restart your Mac!**

[As Uma Madhavi said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146520/ios-app-get-stuck-on-splash-screen#comment54102773_33146520), your Mac may have installed some automatic updates. Restarting it fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I removed Device Support folder and re-open Xcode.

```
rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your root view controller design in storyboard, I also got this issue, In my loginview controller by mistake I have pests/ duplicate UIView into stack view with constraints.
So removed duplicate UIView.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2, xCode 11.5 and simulator version 13.5

Restart or Erase All Content and Settings on the simulator you are using, then try running again. This works for me

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but I just got it and have been searching for two days trying everything without success so far.

What finally worked for me:

- close Xcode
- going into the finder
- go to the list of applications
- select XCode and do Cmd + i
- uncheck the box "Open with rosetta".
- open Xcode and do a clean (cmd + shift + k)

And finally the application has passed the stage of the infinite launch screen

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because Reveal load breakpoint, following Reveal document steps, it works for me. ps: my Reveal version still 26, not upgrade to 38

Reveal document:
https://support.revealapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403215920793-My-app-is-hanging-on-launch-under-Xcode-13-and-iOS-tvOS-15